# Double checked locking with shared_ptr<>

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I have an `unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<foo>>` into which I want to lazily create the instances of `foo` based on callbacks. These callbacks would come from potentially a pool of threads, so to handle this, at the start I create the map and insert empty `shared_ptr<>`s into the map for all possible indexes. Now I have the code below which is designed to create the `foo` instance based on demand.

Is my implementation of double checked locking with `shared_ptr<>` correct?

```
void Publish(const bar& data)  {
    auto id = data.get_id();
    auto it = foos_.find(id);
    if (it == foos_.end()) {
      // throw
    }
    // Check if this is present
    auto sp = std::atomic_load_explicit(&(it->second), std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (!sp) {
      // Create the instance of the foo for this id
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
      (void) lock;
      // Check again
      sp = std::atomic_load_explicit(&(it->second), std::memory_order_relaxed);
      if (!sp) {
        // Create new foo
        sp = std::make_shared<foo>(...);
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
        std::atomic_store_explicit(&(it->second), sp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
      } // Someone else created it...
    }

    // Push the data in
    sp->Publish(data);
  }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `(void) lock;`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ to avoid the unused warning on the lock guard variable. It's only use is to be destroyed at the end of scope.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Would be worth a comment explaining so IMO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, funny you should ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145548/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-statement-voidc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of *Double Checked Locking* is semantically correct; the acquire and release fences provide minimal necessary ordering.

I am wondering why you are using standalone fences, which is almost never necessary..
It is more common to use memory ordering directly on atomic operations:

```
auto sp = std::atomic_load_explicit(&(it->second), std::memory_order_relaxed);
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);

...

std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
std::atomic_store_explicit(&(it->second), sp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Can be replaced with:

```
auto sp = std::atomic_load_explicit(&(it->second), std::memory_order_acquire);

...

std::atomic_store_explicit(&(it->second), sp, std::memory_order_release);
```

Furthermore, I understand why you are using `(void) lock;`, but I would not use that line just to suppress a compiler warning.
Also I am surprised about that warning since a modern compiler should know that RAII objects have a function. Are you sure there is a warning or is that an assumption ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I used a pattern I saw in preshing.com, I was curious as to why he separated the fences too, I guess it's more for clearly highlighting the role of the fences. As for the `(void) lock;` - just habit!